# Linq with transaction

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables : apartments and images, table images has foreign key on table apartments.
How to insert with LINQ ( C#) with transaction  apartment and get that primary key ( apartment.id is auto increment ) so I can insert records in images in same transaction with real  foreign key ?

Comment: Linq is for querying. Can you give an example of what you mean by inserting with Linq?

Comment: Insert new record in table with linq.

Answer (score 1):

Managing Id's?  That's work for the ORM.  Just do this - single transaction, all ids in place, no problem.

```
Apartment newApartment = new Apartment();
newApartment.Images.Add(new Image());
newApartment.Images.Add(new Image());
newApartment.Images.Add(new Image());
newApartment.Images.Add(new Image());

myDataContext.Apartments.Add(newApartment);
myDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform all your operations within an instance of [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
using(var ts = TransactionScope())
{
    yourContext.SubmitChanges();
    ts.Complete();
}
```

I'm not on my PC right now, so I'm not 100 % sure but it should be something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Perform everything in a `TransactionScope`:

```
using(var tx = new TransactionScope())
using(var db = new MyDataContext()) {
    // query db, insert records, etc.
    db.SubmitChanges();
    tx.Complete();
}
```

Be aware that if you haven't already you will need to configure DTC. The instructions vary depending on your operating system (and it's not really a programming issue so I'll leave it at that).